# How to: MySQL How to retrieve record based on three properties?

Tags: sql, rdbms

I am new to SQL and relational DBMS.
I want to retrieve records from a relational database if they satisfy 3 given properties.

For example, if there is a table containing info about solids:

```
table_solid : |s_id|s_name|description|
table_width : |w_id|w_name|
table_height: |h_id|h_name|
table_length: |l_id|l_name|
```

where *_id are all primary keys.

I have 3 more tables for relating these tables with Foreign Keys.

```
table_s_h: |s_id|h_id|
table_s_w: |s_id|w_id|
table_s_l: |s_id|l_id|
```

Would you please explain how do I join these.

Thanks in advance.

```
                 --------- table_length
table_SOLID ----
                ----------- table_width

                ------------table_height
```

table_length contains valid lengths that solid can take (and similarly with other tables).

Comment: What do those tables describe? Their structure and the names of their fields are not very clear.

Comment: I think that you would do better to use one table with 5 or 6 columns.  The 5 columns would be 's_name', 'description', 'w_name', 'l_name' and 'h_name'; the sixth might be an ID for the object.   You seem to have over-normalized and are running into problems as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a single table:

```
Select * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE table_width = SOME_VALUE3
AND table_height= SOME_VALUE2
AND table_length = SOME_VALUE3
```

Is that what you are looking for?  Or are you trying to query multiple tables?  If so try this:

```
Select * 
FROM TABLE_SOLID solid
Inner join table_width width on solid.w_id = width.w_id
inner join table_height height on solid.h_id = height.h_id
inner join table_length length on solid.l_id = length.l_id
```

This link may be of use to you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Yes, I want to query multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your DB schema is not clear to me.

Are these four different tables? If yes, how are they linked up, ie how do you retrieve width, height, length for a given solid?

Or are those four columns in 1 table, identified by s_id?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your schema.

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM
    table_solid AS s
WHERE
    s.s_id IN
(
(SELECT s_id FROM table_s_h INNER JOIN table_height USING (h_id) WHERE h_name = H)
INTERSECT
(SELECT s_id FROM table_s_w INNER JOIN table_width USING (w_id) WHERE w_name = W)
INTERSECT
(SELECT s_id FROM table_s_l INNER JOIN table_length USING (l_id) WHERE l_name = L)
);
```

OT: I don't know if that will work in MySQL and I don't care - I've added "mysql" tag to the question and you've removed it.